# No Reverse Match at

Tags: python, django

I try to redirect to question detailView after answer on question but i get

NoReverseMatch at /98afdfc7-df41-416c-aaae-c1014bfbf119/answer

Reverse for 'question_detail' with arguments '('87',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['questions/(?P[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12})$']

after entering my answer

models

```
class Question(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(_("ID"), primary_key=True,
                          default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    question = models.CharField(_("Question"), max_length=300)


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('question_detail', args=[str(self.id)])


class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, verbose_name=_(
        "Answer"), on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='answers')
    answer = models.CharField(max_length=255)


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('question_detail', args=[str(self.id)])
```

Urls

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('<uuid:pk>/answer', AnswerQuestionView.as_view(), name='answer'),
    path('questions/<uuid:pk>', QuestionDetailView.as_view(),
         name='question_detail'),
]
```

Views

```
class AnswerQuestionView(CreateView):
    model = Answer
    context_object_name = 'answer'
    fields = ['answer', 'question']
    template_name = "forms/answer.html"
   

class QuestionDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Question
    context_object_name = 'question'
    template_name = "question_detail.html"
```

HTML form

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
{{form.as_p}}
<button value="submit">Post</button>
</form>
```

Comment: THe problem is located in the template `QuestionDetailView`, so `question_detail.html`. This likely contains a `{% url ... %}` that does not resolve.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem No, It's empty. Django debug error page refer to get_absolute_url in models.

Comment: The error says: "NoReverseMatch **at /98afdfc7-df41-416c-aaae-c1014bfbf119/answer**", so that is the *path* where the error is *caused*.

Comment: note that after you create an object, it will perform a redirect to the detail view, and likely the page to which the redirect is done, then causes the error.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem You right, object created. this more details shows `Reverse for 'question_detail' with arguments '('87',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['questions/(?P[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12})$']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `id` of your answer is not a `UUID`. Indeed, in your `Answer` model you did not specify a primary key, and in that case [Django automatically adds a primary key that is an `AutoField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields):

> By default, Django gives each model the following field:
>
> ```
> id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
> ```

This thus means that `self.id` of an `Answer` (not a `Question`), is an `int`, and thus this will not match with the `uuid` path converter of the path:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path(
        '<uuid:pk>/answer/',
        AnswerQuestionView.as_view(),
        name='answer'
    ),
    path(
        'questions/<int:pk>/',  # ← use int, not uuid
        QuestionDetailView.as_view(),
        name='question_detail'
    ),
]
```

You can also try to migrate the data to use a uuid instead, but since there is already data, migrating will be more painful.

**EDIT**: It looks however that your `get_absolute_url` of the `Answer` aims to refer to the detail view of the `Question`. Since a [**`get_absolute_url()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url) should return a *canonical* url, this is not really how a `get_absolute_url()` is supposed to work.

If you want to specify the id of the `Question`, then you use:

```
class Answer(models.Model):
    # …
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('question_detail', args=(self.question_id,))
```

In that case of course the path should use the `uuid`.

Comment: Redirected to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/questions/91` `Page not found` and id 91 refer to the answer. i need to get question detail with related answers.

Comment: @OmarElweshy: but the `model` of this view is `Question`, not `Answer`. If you want to redirect to the detail view of the question. This violates the fact that `get_absolute_url` should return a *canonical* URL. You can use `self.question_id` instead (see edit), but still it is not how `get_absolute_url` is supposed to work.